# How to make a variable available to all my pages in Laravel

Tags: laravel, autoload

I want to be able to make a variable available in any page I wish.

For example, I want to have `$website_name` always available so I can show it in the header.

How and where can I create `$website_name` and store a value into it?

Answer (score 4):

You can share data with all views using your `AppServiceProvider` located in your `providers` directory. In the boot() method, use the `view()` helper and assign data.

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider 
{
    public function boot() 
    {
        view()->share('website_name', 'My website');
    }
}
```

You can use it like any other variable in your view.

```
{{ $website_name }}
```

Docs: [Sharing data with all views](http://laravel.com/docs/master/views#sharing-data-with-all-views)

Comment: I test this idea and worked great but if I want write more handle function and they are working  first , Write this function here in AppServiceProvider ?!

and thank you for your helping

Comment: Sure, you can fire off whatever you want in your Service providers. Create a method which retrieves the data you want, from a database or whatever source you're using, and assign the data using the `share` method as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You can store data in sessions, which is availabel across page requests. To set a variable you can use:

```php
Session::put('website_name', 'Value Goes Here');
```

To retrieve the value you can use:

```php
Session::get('website_name');
```

You can also use method dependency injection to access the session like explained in the [Laravel Session Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session#basic-usage).

Comment: Okey ! but in this case i want run this code in the first !! where I should put this code ?
and Thank you For your Reply

Answer (score 0):

You would write `$website_name` in a `view composer`, similar to what Magnussen suggested in his answer. For starters you can try the following within the `boot` method of the `AppServiceProvider`:

```
View::composer('*', function($view)
{
    $view->with('website_name', 'My website');
});
```

The `*` means all *views* will receive `$website_name`.

Keep in mind this will make `$website_name` available only to `views`.

You can also opt for the `Config` approach.

Instead of the `view composer` above, try the following within the `boot` method of the `AppServiceProvider`:

```
$website = ['name' => 'My website', 'url' => 'myapp.com'];
Config::set('website', $website);
```

Now anywhere within your code you can grab the value as `Config::get('website.name')`.

Comment: Thank you for your help I try this now

Answer (score 0):

If the website name is always the same, simply add a key/value pair named 'name' to your app config file. Then access it in any views or anywhere in your app using

```
Config::get('app.name')
```

Alternatively, if you are dynamically working out the website name for some reason, you can create a new middleware using

```
php artisan make:middleware SomeMiddleware
```

In this middleware, check if the Session has a key named 'website_name'

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!Session::has('website_name')) {
        // some logic
        Session::put('website_name', 'YOUR VALUE');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Then in your view use

```
{{Session::get('website_name', 'Value Goes Here')}}
```

You should check Chris Magnussen's answer though as that is the recommended way of sharing data with views

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help as we're using Laravel Spark with our site, but...

In our site, we have each page title set up like this:

```
<title>Page Title - Site Name</title>
```

To achieve this, within `/config/app.php`, line 15 looks like this:

```
'name' => 'Site Name',
```

and `/resources/views/vendor/spark/layouts/app.blade.php`, has this:

```
<title>@yield('title') - {{ config('app.name') }}</title>
```

Then, on individual page views, for example, `/resources/views/home.blade.php` we've added:

```
@section('title','Page Title')
```